# zeppelin error: object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

I wrote an hbase query in scala spark and it works well. I want to implement it in a zeppelin notebook and i have this error :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client._
 error: object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop
```

i already set the hbase interpreter wuth hbase home and the dependencies, now i don't know what can i do...

the hbase interpreter is like this :

```
Properties
name    value
hbase.home  /usr/hdp/current/hbase-master
hbase.ruby.sources  lib/ruby
zeppelin.hbase.test.mode    false

Dependencies
artifact    exclude
/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/lib/hbase-client.jar  
/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/lib/hbase-protocol.jar    
/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/lib/hbase-common.jar
```

Thk's in advance !

Comment: You need to include the HBase JAR in the SparkHome, or if I remember correctly Zeppelin provides a way to configure the Spark interpreter adding custom JARs. Also, note that it may require a couple of JARs until everything works.